# How to delegate a query function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Web page: [link to page](http://www.palmirainteriores.es). If you go to the "Galería" section, you can see a slider of photographs and a menu on your left side. Each image on the slider is clickable, and if you click, you fill the white space with the photograph you just clicked.

Correct till there.

The thing is that, when you wanna change the section (on your left, the menu that says "Nuestra tienda 2011", "Mayo 2012"), supposely what I do is change the content of the **ul** gallery on the bottom side.

To do so, I wrote this code:

```
<div id="lista_galerias">
            <ul>
                <li><div id="nuestra_tienda_show">Nuestra tienda 2011</div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#nuestra_tienda_show').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.jCarousel').html('');
                            $('<ul><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." width="100" height="100"></img></div></li></ul>')
                                .prependTo('jCarousel');
                            $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Nuestra tienda 2011');
                        });

                    </script>
                </li>
                <li><div id="mayo_2012_show">Mayo 2012</div>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#mayo_2012_show').click(function()
                        {
                            $('.jCarousel').html('');
                            $('<ul><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Mayo_2012/img1.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100"></img></div></li></ul>')
                                .prependTo('.jCarousel');
                            $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Mayo 2012');
                        });

                    </script>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And the jCarousel div:

```
<!-- DIV Contenedor de la imagen de la galería -->
        <div id="containerGaleria">
            <div id="containerImage"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- DIV Contenedor de la galeria de imágenes -->
        <div class="container_carousel">
            <div class="jCarousel">
                <ul>
                    <li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="1" width="100" height="100"></div></li>
                    <li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img2.jpg" alt="2" width="100" height="100"></div></li>
                    <li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img3.jpg" alt="3" width="100" height="100"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="prev"><<</button>
            <button class="next">>></button>
        </div>
```

As you can see, I have a **div** that contains the jCarousel, and another one with the list of sections that modifies the content of this jCarousel div.

So **MY DOUBT IS**:

I guess that maybe when I erase the html content of the jCarousel, for some reason it doesn't reload the jCarousel effect, and it shows... well, as a plain list with no properties. How can I reload that jCarousel list to see like when the first load of the page??

**EDIT:**I added this:

```
$('#nuestra_tienda_show').click(function()
    {
        $('.jCarousel').html('');
        $('<ul><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." width="100" height="100"></img></div></li></ul>')
            .prependTo('.jCarousel');
        $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Nuestra tienda 2011');
                            $('.jCarousel').jCarouselLite({
                                btnNext: ".next",
                                btnPrev: ".prev"
                           });
                        });
```

But then, my list doesn't appear. Even if I only add

```
$('.jCarousel').jCarouselLite();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get in the page, but it seems like you are missing a call to .jCarousel
When you erase all the contents of the carousel ($('.jCarousel').html('');) and add new content, all the events and everything of the jcarousel goes away. So:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nuestra_tienda_show').click(function()
    {
        $('.jCarousel').html(''); // Here, you loose all jcarousel events, etc
        $('<ul><li><div id="clickable"><img src="img/Escaparates_2011/img1.jpg" alt="Dormitorio azul turquesa." width="100" height="100"></img></div></li></ul>')
         .prependTo('jCarousel'); // this element is unknown to jcarousel
        $('.jCarousel').jCarousell(); // Initialize the carousel again
        $('#galeria_seleccionada').html('Nuestra tienda 2011');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which list doesn't load?? It's prepending it to the .jCarousel div, it should be there...

Comment: Yes, I prepend it, but if I try to launch the event, it doesn't appear! I edit the post so you can see.

Comment: Yes, the ul is there, but not the event.

Comment: I'm not getting it... Which event isn't there?

Comment: I mean, when you first load the page, it's a slider what you can see, that you can go through using arrows. But if I change the code, for some reason, that slider doesn't appear. It should be because the onload() event of the page was done before, and then this new list is not loaded as a slider. But I don't know how to solve that...

Comment: Ok, sorry, it has something to do with the slider by itself... Thanks anyways!